# Carrierwave remove method based on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I have multiple Carrierwave attachment fields in my model which I would like to be able remove in my show view. As there are multiple fields I pass a parameter to my controller method so it knows which file to remove:

```
def remove_attachment
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post["remove_#{params[:attachment]}!"]
  post.save
  redirect_to post
end
```

However, the following line does not work `post["remove_#{params[:attachment]}!"]`? Not sure where I am going wrong here?

I've tested the following which does work:

```
def remove_attachment
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.remove_compliance_guide! # one of the attachment fields
  post.save
  redirect_to post
end
```

I realise that I could do the below but I think my first solution is cleaner.

```
def remove_attachment
  post = Bid.find(params[:id])

  if params[:attachment] == 'compliance_guide'
    post.remove_compliance_guide!
  elsif params[:attachment] == 'compliance_other'
    post.remove_compliance_other!
  elsif params[:attachment] == 'compliance_agreement'
    post.remove_compliance_agreement!
  end
  post.save
  redirect_to post
end
```

Just in case I've made a mistake somewhere else:

route: `post 'posts/:id/remove_attachment', to: 'posts#remove_attachment'`

view link: `link_to 'Remove', { controller: 'post', action: "remove_attachment", attachment: 'compliance_guide', id: @post.id }, method: 'post', class: "file-remove right"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `send` to invoke a method by passing its name as a string:

```
def remove_attachment
  post = Post.find(params[:id])
  post.send("remove_#{params[:attachment]}!")
  post.save
  redirect_to post
end
```

Note that a `NoMethodError` will be raised if the attachment doesn't exist. You could work around that using something like:

```
if post.respond_to?("remove_#{params[:attachment]}!")
  post.send("remove_#{params[:attachment]}!")
  post.save
end
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Also check the comment I made regarding possible `NoMethodError`s, in case it applies to your app.

Comment: Thank you it does apply to my app. Very much appreciate it!